# Transit visa needed? Canada > Vienna > Iran

Tags: visas, schengen, transit, iranian-citizens, vie

Do I need a transit visa to travel from Canada through Vienna to Iran?
I am an Iranian citizen and I am staying in Canada on a Visa. Now I am returning to Iran and my flight has a layover time of 11 hours in Vienna. Do I need a transit visa for Austria?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that Iranian passport holders who hold a Canadian visa do not need a Schengen transit visa, **if** you remain airside for the entire 11 hours. From [Visa policy of the Schengen area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_the_Schengen_Area#Airport_transit):

> However, citizens of the above 12 countries are exempt from airport transit visas if they:
>
> - hold a valid visa for an EU member state or for a member of the European Economic Area Agreement, **Canada**, Japan or the United States of America, or when they return from those countries after having used the visa,

However, you may need to confirm with the airport that (a) the airside lounge remains open for your intended 11 hour stay and does not close; and (b) there are facilities such as food available. If you cannot remain airside for your entire layover duration for any reason, you will need to get a Schengen visa.